# What is the 'main' difference between patterns and constructors - Haskell

Tags: haskell

**What is the 'main' difference between patterns and constructors?**

*Answer:*

```
With a constructor you can add a tag to your data, in such a way that it receives a type.

Patters will be more used for matching data with a pattern, which isn't the case of a constructor. 
Patters can also be used for the destruction reasons.
```

Comment: Can you please make your question more precise? I'm not sure what you're aiming at, the two are for different purposes, a constructor constructs values, and patterns are used to take values apart (broadly speaking).

Answer (score 7):

As Daniel Fisher said, constructors build some value, and patterns take it apart:

```
data Person = P String String Int

-- constructor to build a value
makePerson firstname lastname age = P firstname lastname age 

-- pattern to take a value apart
fullName (P firstname lastname _) = firstname ++ " " + lastname
```

Note that this is just an example, for this particular type the record syntax would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

In some sense they're very similar to one another as they are dual. Constructors can be thought of as an algebra of the signature functor of a data type and patterns coalgebras on that same functor.

To be more explicit, let's consider `[]`. It's signature functor is `T_A X = 1 + A * X` or, in Haskell

```
type ListF a x = Maybe (a, x)
```

with the obvious `Functor` instance. We can see that `ListF`-algebras with a `List` carrier are just its constructors

```
-- general definition
type Algebra f a = f a -> a

consList :: Algebra (ListF a) [a]
consList Nothing        = []
consList (Just (a, as)) = a:as
```

Dually, we can look at the coalgebra of `ListF` with `List` as its carrier

```
type Coalgebra f a = a -> f a

unconsList :: Coalgebra (ListF a) [a]
unconsList []     = Nothing
unconsList (a:as) = Just (a, as)
```

and further see that the safe versions of `head` and `tail` are very natural destructors on `[]`

```
headMay :: [a] -> Maybe a
headMay = fmap fst . unconsList

tailMay :: [a] -> Maybe a
tailMay = fmap snd . unconsList
```

This fuels a personal pet peeve about `head` and `tail` not even being particularly nice functions ignoring their partiality---they're only natural on infinite lists which have signature functors `T A X = A*X`.

Now in Haskell the [initial `Algebra` and final `Coalgebra`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects) of a functor coincide as the fixed-point of that functor

```
newtype Fix f = Fix { unfix :: f (Fix f) }
```

Which is exactly what data types are. We can prove that `[a]` is isomorphic to `Fix (ListF a)`

```
fwd :: [a] -> Fix (ListF a)
fwd []     = Fix Nothing
fwd (a:as) = Fix (Just (a, fwd as))

bwd :: Fix (ListF a) -> [a]
bwd (Fix Nothing)           = []
bwd (Fix (Just (a, fixed))) = a : bwd fixed
```

This provides justification for using the data type itself as both constructors and patterns, but if you create other kinds of "coalgebra-like" things then you can have first-class patterns such as those provided by [She](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/she/patsy.html) or [pattern combinators](http://reinerp.wordpress.com/category/pattern-combinators/).

For a deeper understanding of the duality of patterns and constructors, try doing this exercise above again with a data type like

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Branch (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

Its signature functor is `T A X = 1 + X*A*X` or

```
type TreeF a x = Maybe (x,a,x)
```